# Javascript document.cookie works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

Well I have this javascript that sets cookie in javascript, which stores a serialized json event object. It works fine on Chrome but not on Firefox, why does this happen? Can anyone please help?

```
document.cookie="cjaxevent="
                 + CJAX.serializeEvent(e)
                 + "; expires=" 
                 + new Date(e.timeStamp + 30000).toGMTString() 
                 + "; path=/; domain=." 
                 + document.domain;
```

Comment: And the code works in IE too, its very strange why it does not work on Firefox.

Comment: What is the hostname?

Comment: I am on a webhost called webhostingbuzz. But anyway, its irrelevant to the problem. i ran some test and apparently, the time is incorrect. new Date(e.timeStamp + 30000).toGMTString() gives a date in 1970, so the cookie is not set because it already expired. Strangely, only firefox behaves this way, the date is correct on Chrome and IE.

Comment: `e.timeStamp` is work incorrect in FireFox for `events`. I get the same errors in project when I try to sort events by its `e.timeStamp` and always get wrong ordering in FireFox

Comment: I see, thank you so much. I found the solution already. Replace e.timestamp by Date.now() fixes the issue.